# unable to use package function during command line compilation

Tags: java

I am using apache commons IO for copying files and have imported that as

**import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;**

but during compilation of my single class that has a main function (only for testing the functions of commons IO) say the
**Error: package org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils doesn't exist**

> I have placed both java class file and the package apache file the
> same folder.

How can I use the function of apache package in my normal file which I am compiling by command line tools IDE like Eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add apache commons.jar and all other required jars in [classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131036/how-to-use-org-apache-commons-package).

Comment: Read the link added in my answer. It has steps on how to do.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add all external JAR files to the build path:

http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-%28Java%29