# Configure a path on eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I new to android, and  when running my project , I always get this error :

1. The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for org.apache.http.HttpEntity. Fix the build path then try building this project           Unknown Java Problem
2. The type org.apache.http.HttpEntity cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files   AndroidMultiPartEntity.java     line 13 Java Problem

After fixing this, I've a new one :

> cvc-complex-type.2.4.d : Contenu non valide trouvé à partir de l'élément 'd:skin'. Aucun élément enfant n'est attendu à cet endroit.

Code

```
package com.menasys.classroom.utils; 
import java.io.FilterOutputStream; 
import java.io.IOException; 
import java.io.OutputStream; 
import java.nio.charset.Charset; 
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.HttpMultipartMode; 

import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity;
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation") public class AndroidMultiPartEntity extends MultipartEntity
```

Comment: Is org.apache.http.HttpEntity a jar file?

Comment: [Can you use apache commons library into your project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131036/how-to-use-org-apache-commons-package)? if yes did you added `org.apache.http.HttpEntity` into the class? also please, provide the code giving this error

Comment: @Materazzi06 :is a org.apache.http.HttpEntity

Comment: package com.menasys.classroom.utils;

import java.io.FilterOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
 
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.HttpMultipartMode;
this is my code :                                                                                 import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity;
 
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")

public class AndroidMultiPartEntity extends MultipartEntity

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I have fixed the English issues with your post.  I have also added the code from your comment.   Please remember to do that in the future.  You can always edit and clarify your question.  Please peruse the code and ensure that it has been transcribed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not using the jar correctly.
Please download the jar from http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/a/Downloadapachehttpcomponentshttpcorejar.htm and unzip the file. Now in your eclipse, right click on your project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Add External jars -> Add the jar(which you got by unzipping). Press Apply and OK.

Comment: After doing waht you have saying , i have this error : 
ClientProtocolException cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: Are you using this import? import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;

Comment: The import org.apache.http.client cannot be resolved

Comment: how do i knouw ?? using the import ?? i am new in android ??

Comment: Use this jar(4.5.1) from http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi and try the above steps which I gave in my Answer

Comment: wher the file.jar i find it in .zip

Comment: unzip it -> you have the folder -> go to libs folder and there u find httpclient.jar

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94316/discussion-between-materazzi06-and-user3070123).

Comment: I 've  this pb now : cvc-complex-type.2.4.d : Contenu non valide trouvé à partir de l'élément 'd:skin'. Aucun élément enfant n'est attendu à cet endroit.

Comment: Please describe it in English