# Program that chose the method to use based on the argument's suffix of the input

Tags: java, apache

How can we implement a general program that takes an argument but based on the suffix of the input files (.csv or .ser) it chooses which mechanism to use to read the data.

I found the code below somewhere in StackOverflow: however, I am not sure how to apache package and how to set it up.
I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131036/how-to-use-org-apache-commons-package) but still can't figure it out.

Is there a way to do that with only java library?

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils;
class FileExtension{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String ext1 = FilenameUtils.getExtension("//path//to//your//file");
        if(ext1.equals("csv")){
            //call csv function to read data
        }else if(ext1.equals("ser")){
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What build tool are you using, is it _Maven_ project, _Gradle_, IDE specific build, etc.?

Comment: Hi David, pls check this URL: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/commons_io/commons_io_filenameutils.htm

Answer (score 0):

You don't need external library to get the extension of a file, a simple function like the one below should meet your needs:

```
public static String getExtension(String filename) 
{       
    int index = filename.lastIndexOf(".");
    if ( (index == -1) || (index == filename.length() - 1) )
        return "";      
    else            
        return filename.substring(index);   
}
```